# iloc on loop returns "single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" error

Tags: python, indexing

This is the code:

```
for e in range(1, len(db.index)):
    g.append((db.iloc[e + 1, 1] - db.iloc[e, 1]) * 100.0 / db.iloc[e, 1])
```

The dataframe (db) has 2 colums and 284 rows. I'm trying to find the average growth rate for the second column. I've tried everything but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Try clarify your question by adding examples of your data and the output you are  looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `range()` function it is safer to just iterate through the index, ie.:

```
for e in db.index:
    g.append((db.iloc[e+1, 1] - db.iloc[e, 1]) * 100.0 / db.iloc[e,1])
```

Also you can optimize this code further and get rid of the for loop altogether, ie.:

```
db.iloc[:,1].diff().multiply(100).div(db.iloc[:,1].shift())
```

This code will return a `pd.Series` that you can assign to your `g`:

```
g = db.iloc[:,1].diff().multiply(100).div(db.iloc[:,1].shift())
```

or append to it if it already contains some data:

```
g = pd.concat([g, db.iloc[:,1].diff().multiply(100).div(db.iloc[:,1].shift())
])
```

If you follow my suggestion, then you can also use the name of the column 1 straight away rather than using the `iloc` slicer for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Your range is one step too long, if you want to use `e+1` for indexing. Try:

```
for e in range(1, len(db.index) -1):  # one step shorter
    g.append((db.iloc[e + 1, 1] - db.iloc[e, 1]) * 100.0 / db.iloc[e, 1])
```